# how to use variable in recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion

I am learning recursion in python. I wrote a program but it is not working correctly. I am a beginner in python. I have two functions **scrabbleScore()** and **letterScore()**. **scrabbleScore()** calls **letterscore()** and itself also. Here is my code:

```
def letterScore( let ):
    if let in ['a','e','i','l','n','o','r','s','t','u']:
        return 1
    elif let in ['d','g']:
        return 2
    elif let in ['b','c','m','p']:
        return 3
    elif let in ['f','h','v','w','y']:
        return 4
    elif let=='k':
        return 5
    elif let in ['j','x']:
        return 8
    elif let in ['q','z']:
        return 10
    else:
        return 0

p = 0
def scrabbleScore( S ):
    if S == "":
        return 0
    else:
        global p
        p=p+letterScore(S[0])
        scrabbleScore(S[1:])
        return p

print "scrabbleScore('quetzal'):  25 ==", scrabbleScore('quetzal')
print "scrabbleScore('jonquil'):  23 ==", scrabbleScore('jonquil')
print "scrabbleScore('syzygy'):   25 ==", scrabbleScore('syzygy')
print "scrabbleScore('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'):  87 ==", scrabbleScore('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
print "scrabbleScore('?!@#$%^&*()'):  0 ==", scrabbleScore('?!@#$%^&*()')
print "scrabbleScore(''):          0 ==", scrabbleScore('')
```

Comment: Why it is not working correctly? What is the expected result? What do you receive instead?

Comment: Please post your code here, not on another site.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Yes i have done mistake, I will remember this things next time. By the way, now my code working with the below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working correctly because you are using global variable for storing intermediate results. After you call "scrabbleScore" for the first time p value would become 25 and you need to reset it.

The solution here would be to avoid using global variable at all:

```
def scrabbleScore( S ):
    p = 0
    if S == "":
        return 0
    else:
        p = p + letterScore(S[0])
        p = p + scrabbleScore(S[1:])
        return p
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite your scrabbleScore to something like this

```
def scrabbleScore(S):
    def helper(S, p):
        if S == "":
            return p
        else:
            p += letterScore(S[0])
            return helper(S[1:], p)

    return helper(S, 0)
```

this is how you could write it. `p` is called a akkumulator and should not be global (in general, global variabls should be avoided). I didn't figured out why your programm does not work, but my will print the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `p` should be initialized to zero again after each call to `scrabbleScore(S)`. This will solve your problem. Example:

```
print "scrabbleScore('quetzal'):  25 ==", scrabbleScore('quetzal')
p=0
print "scrabbleScore('jonquil'):  23 ==", scrabbleScore('jonquil')
```